# Any thoughts on how to execute this php in javascript, or alternative method on shopify?

Tags: javascript, php, shopify

JUST got this all sorted out for php - and realized shopify doesn't support php in themes....  Meaning I need to resort to converting this to javascript, or? Would love thoughts or help converting.

```
<?php
$file = fopen('storelistdata.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
list($country, $state, $city, $loc) = $line;
echo "<a class=\"item\">$loc, $city, $state, $country</a>\n";
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Shopify will NEVER deal with your PHP. Here is the standard acceptable way for you to work this out with Shopify Themes.

- Create a basic simple PHP App you can install in the Shop.
- Add a route in your App that listens to a GET
- that GET route code will then open the CSV file and return the data inside it (as HTML/Liquid or JSON, your choice)
- If you want the customer to change that file, allow them to do a file upload or edit in your App. Pretty standard stuff there.
- Add an App Proxy to your App that will point at your route for the GET

Add a Javascript callback in their theme where you want the data in the CSV to be rendered. This callback will naturally be a GET to that route in your App. Note that the Proxy can return JSON, making it really simple for you to append JSON data to the DOM

To summarize, this pattern is secure, simple enough, and allows you to present your Shopify merchants with a method of working with a CSV for purposes special to their shop.

Comment: Ah - ok - puts this into perspective. Honestly that's a lot more time than I'd want to spend on this considering how simple it'd be otherwise. I might just run it nestled from another server.

Comment: Your only choice is likely an <iframe>. And you know that means zero interactivity with the Shopify flow.. it will be nothing more than a decoration.

Comment: I might just format all the data for the page. There are jquery alternatives but they're slightly lengthier - still rather 30 lines of code

Comment: You cannot call back your own server without triggering a CORS restriction. OK. Fine. So you allow the world to hit your server and you can then deliver the content. Not smart, not secure, but in a pinch, gets the data. Your merchant may never even know you are hacking like that.

Comment: Just trying to save you from wasting a ton of time with trying things that won't work! Peace!